# How to summarize multiple rows in a single new row in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe of states and certain population

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  region        selected_pop
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 Connecticut       59306
2 Maine             85416
3 Massachusetts     83870
4 New Hampshire     62250
5 New Jersey       533328
6 New York         197454
7 Pennsylvania      35732
8 Rhode Island      85614
9 Vermont            3414
```

and I want to create an output that looks like this, where totalpop is sum of population of each state. How would I do this in r?

```
region Totalpop
Northeast 1146384
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dataset have only 'Northeast' states, an option is to change the 'region' to 'Northeast' in `group_by` and `summarise` the 'selected_pop'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(region = 'Northeast') %>%
     summarise(Total_pop = sum(selected_pop))
```

Comment: thank you. if I had the southern states in the same dataframe and wanted to sort by 'northeast' and 'south'  to get an output like below, how would I apply two filters and group_by?

`region Totalpop
Northeast 1146384
South  545349`

Comment: @onjalo You may have a list of 'state' that belong to 'Northest', then just do `df1 %>% group_by(region = case_when(region %in% yourvectorofnortheaststates ~ 'Northeast', TRUE ~ 'South')) %>% summarise(Total_pop = sum(selected_pop))`. If there are multiple sets, either creaate a key/val data.frame, do a join and then use the new value column as group to get the `sum` of 'selected_pop'